# Setup SSL with Lets Encrypt on RHEL

Tags: ssl, amazon-ec2, redhat, lets-encrypt

I'm trying to setup the ssl certificate with Letsencrypt but when i run :

```
./letsencrypt-auto --apache -d industriemedia.tv
```

It looks like my domain name cannot be found:

```
[root@ip-172-31-21-7 letsencrypt]# ./letsencrypt-auto --apache -d industriemedia.tv
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Obtaining a new certificate
Performing the following challenges:
tls-sni-01 challenge for industriemedia.tv

We were unable to find a vhost with a ServerName or Address of industriemedia.tv.
Which virtual host would you like to choose?
(note: conf files with multiple vhosts are not yet supported)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1: ssl.conf                       |                       | HTTPS | Enabled
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

But i have added a virtualhost in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.industriemedia.tv
  ServerAlias industriemedia.tv *.industriemedia.tv
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: have you tried `./letsencrypt-auto --apache -d www.industriemedia.tv`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to open the port 443 which haven't been opened.

Also doing a ./letsencrypt-auto reset my ssl certificate and my domain was recognized.